# Rails Sunspot Kaminari Max results 30

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sunspot, kaminari

I'm using Sunspot and Kaminari for pagination. However, I'm seeing that the max results returned (even though there is more) is 30.

Here's my code:

```
Kaminari.paginate_array(search.results).page(params[:page]).per(10)
```

Please advise on how to return all results and paginate accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[All results from Solr are paginated... By default, Sunspot requests the first 30 results from Solr](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot#pagination). In your example, you're paginating the array of the first 30 results returned by Solr.

I find it easiest to just call `paginate` in the search blocks in my controllers...

```
@search = Sunspot.search(BlogPost) do
  # filters...
  paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)
end
```

Then use Kaminari's paginate helper in my views...

```
<%= paginate @search.results %>
```

* you could use `@search.hits` if you don't want to load model instances

---

Alternatively, it [looks like](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari#paginating-a-generic-array-object) you can pass in `:total_count` as a keyword argument to Kaminari's `paginate_array` method. So this should work if you want to stick with the method you're using above...

```
Kaminari.paginate_array(search.results, total_count: search.total).page(params[:page]).per(10)
```

Comment: Hey, you answer is correct. Thank you. It turns out I was calling paginate outside the search block :(